# The method add(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, WeatherFragment)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments, import

I have error in fragment:

> "The method replace(int, Fragment) in the type Fragment Transaction is
>   not applicable for the arguments (int, Fragment)"

What should I do? My fragment doesn't appear.

```
    package com.example.weather;

    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

    import android.text.InputType;
    import android.app.AlertDialog;

    import android.content.DialogInterface;

    import android.os.Bundle;

    import android.view.LayoutInflater;

    import android.view.Menu;

    import android.view.MenuItem;

    import android.view.View;

    import android.view.ViewGroup;

    import android.widget.EditText;

    import android.os.Build;

    public class WeatherActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_weather);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new WeatherFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.change_city){
            showInputDialog();
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void showInputDialog(){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Change city");
        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        builder.setView(input);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Go", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                changeCity(input.getText().toString());
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    public void changeCity(String city){
        WeatherFragment wf = (WeatherFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.container);
        wf.changeCity(city);
        new CityPreference(this).setCity(city);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you defined your own type called Fragment which doesn't extend android.app.Fragment?

Comment: Error in title doesn't match error in question. Please decide on the error that you need help with.

Comment: Excuse me, can not understand clearly say

Comment: There is an error in the line and I can not solve the problem
Sorry for my English, I'm a little weak type

Answer (score 1):

The import of fragment should be changed.
This is wrong:-

`import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`

Correct import is:-

`import android.app.Fragment;`

Comment: How do you know he isn't using a support fragment?

Comment: Previously it took me two days for solving the same problem at beginner level. So i'm just guessing it. Might be helpful

Comment: Ah okay. The answer just made it seem like a fact, but I couldn't identify how you knew it to be the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I solve it when I realized that:

`WebViewFragment` is subclass of `android.app.Fragment` , so you can't add it using `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`. you must use `android.app.FragmentManager`

SO I do the following steps to be able to use `WebViewFragment`

1. I change the superclass of my Fragments to `android.app.Fragment` instead of `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`
2. I changed the `FragmentManager` to `android.app.FragmentManager` instead of `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`
3. I use `getFragmentManager()` instead of `getSupportFragmentManager`

I hope that would be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Well whatever WeatherFragment is, it is not of the Fragment type and no constructor exists which can handle a WeatherFragment. <s>Maybe you can cast it to Fragment. Cant tell without knowing what it is.</s>

Early morning blunder. The first part of the answer stands ;) He is using his own class `WeatherFragment`. Without being able to see this, I assume it isn't a (proper) fragment.

Comment: You definitely can't cast something which isn't a subtype of Fragment to a Fragment.

Comment: So I replaced it with a piece Treeline

Comment: No one to help me out
Please